# Doctrine - Relacionamento One-To-Many

Tags: php, doctrine

Boa tarde!

Estou fazendo um relacionamento com o Doctrine e me surgiu uma dúvida.
Tenho 2 tabelas no meu banco de dados, a tabela de Log e a tabela de 
Detalhes do log, onde 1 log pode conter vários registros a ele referenciados 
na tabela Detalhes do log. Gostaria de fazer o relacionamento One-To-Many 
entre essas tabelas, mas ainda tenho uma dúvida quanto a isso.

Eu entendi a questão dos annotations do doctrine, onde vou fazer a amarração entre
as entidades e referências entre os campos chaves, mas não consegui entender
como vou fazer para armazenar uma lista de objetos do detalhes do log dentro do log.

Não sei se consegui ser claro na minha explanação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponhamos que você tenha uma tabela `Log` e uma `LogDetalhe`. Antes de mais nada você criará as entidades que serão mapeadas para as tabelas correspondentes:

Tabela `Log`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Log
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LogDetalhe", mappedBy="log")
     */
    protected $logDetalhes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->logDetalhes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getLogDetalhes()
    {
        return $this->logDetalhes;
    }

    public function addLogDetalhe(LogDetalhe $logDetalhe)
    {
        $this->logDetalhes->add($logDetalhe);

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLogDetalhe(LogDetalhe $logDetalhe)
    {
        $this->logDetalhes->remove($logDetalhe);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Tabela `LogDetalhe`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class LogDetalhe
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Log", inversedBy="logDetalhes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $log;

    public function getLog()
    {
        return $this->log;
    }

    public function setLog(Log $log)
    {
        $this->log = $log;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Note que o relacionamento é bidirecional porque não apenas eu desejo pegar os detalhes a partir do log, como desejo pegar o log a partir de um detalhe específico.

Depois, para criar um log e seus detalhes correspondentes, bastaria fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
$log = new Log();
$this->manager->persist($log);

$logDetalhe1 = (new LogDetalhes())->setLog($log);
$this->manager->persist($logDetalhe1);

$logDetalhe2 = (new LogDetalhes())->setLog($log);
$this->manager->persist($logDetalhe2);

$logDetalhe3 = (new LogDetalhes())->setLog($log);
$this->manager->persist($logDetalhe3);

$this->manager->flush();
```

Veja que primeiramente o `Log` foi criado, e depois relacionei diversas entidades do tipo `LogDetalhe` ao primeiro. Cada uma dessas entidades deve ser persistida por meio do `EntityManager` do Doctrine, para, então, serem salvas no banco por meio do método `flush()`.

Comment: E se quisesse fazer um relacionamento unidirecional? como deveria proceder nesse caso? Quando pesquisar algum log que tenha mais de um detalhe cadastrado tem alguma forma do doctrine popular automaticamente os objetos?

Comment: Nesse caso você remove a propriedade que não precisa mais e também os atributos `mappedBy` e `inversedBy` de cada um dos lados. Já que você não pegaria os detalhes diretamente por meio do modelo, dá pra usar os métodos do `EntityRepository` para pegar um log e seus detalhes usando uma DQL (Doctrine Query Language).

Comment: Desculpe a minha ignorância amigo, não sei se é isso que você tentou me explicar, mas eu gostaria de manter um relacionamento unidirecional entre as tabelas, onde através do log eu consiga acessar os seus detalhes, e dentro do objeto log armazenar um array com os detalhes do log em questão. Gostaria de saber também como proceder para realizar um método onde popularia o objeto log e com os seus devidos detalhes aninhados.